# Iterating over checkboxes with same x-path in TestSigma

Tags: testing

Use case: There is a list of checkboxes with some of them are checked. I have to iterate over the checkboxes (all checkboxes are with same x-path) and have to check that are not checked. I am using while loop for iteration with condition "while element[x-path] is visible on the page". Followed by a If condition to check the box

Problem : In TestSigma The loop iterates only upto the first unchecked checkbox and checks it and stops iterating others. Help me on this issue.